# Why did Lumen really leave?

Tags: plot-explanation, dexter

In the end of season 5 of Dexter, Lumen suddenly leaves, even though they made the perfect couple.

The reason she gives, that she no longer has the need to kill while Dexter still does, feels very weak and far from being sufficient, so I'm pretty sure there is other reason or reasons.

What are those real reasons? Is this explained somewhere at some point, in show or outside the show, e.g. interview with actor or producer of the show? (I did not watch further seasons yet.)

Comment: *(I did not watch further seasons yet.)* Don't. It's not even funny how bad that show gets.

Comment: @phantom42 well, I watched The Leftovers to the very end and was really disappointed with the way it ended. Judging from what I've seen so far in Dexter and spoilers I saw here and there, I won't be that disappointed with whatever waiting in the next seasons. Maybe not as thrilled as I was at first, or less fun than what I had so far even in season 5, but I doubt they'll suddenly make major changes. Dexter kills people, Dexter finding new things about himself, etc. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is never further explained beyond this point. However, there are some things to consider:

- Lumen did have a fiancé and it's possible that she wants to return to her alleged life in Minneapolis, MN.
- As the show continues, her departure does a few things/is used as a plot device (**Minor Spoilers Ahead**):

  - Sets the stage for future seasons, which continues to show how "human" Dexter is becoming by showing his feelings/vulnerabilities, which causes more insane plots.
  - Establishes *Dexter's* themes & tone (no matter what Dexter does, the "universe" never lets him get exactly what he wants).

> And in the final season, one can see how another character has aspects or elements of each of Dexter's previous love interests (sex appeal of Lila, the nuturing aspect of Rita, and the ideal partner in crime like Lumen). This also feeds into other concepts, full-circling the series (or really, Dexter's childhood trauma) by indirectly tying back to Dexter's mother.

Comment: I too had a hard time initially buying that Lumen could just be cured and/or would just leave, because she no longer has the urge/dark passenger in common with Dexter. The fanfic that *only exists in my mind* is a Lumen spin-off where perhaps she plays vigilanti elsewhere and maybe tries to save people from human trafficing in New Mexico with her alien-obsessed best friend, Rusty.